# Magento Fancybox

Tags: magento, fancybox

I am new to Magento, in the checkout page. I have a text field and onblur of the text field will open a fancy box popup.
so in the checkout.phtml I placed a div to show their content in the pop up and set CSS attribute display as none.

In on blur I called a JS function and load the poup, for that I write the JS function - jQuery(".zipformcont").fancybox().trigger('click');

zipformcont is class name of div.

The issue is pop up is loading with an error - "The requested content cannot be loaded.
Please try again later."

Please help me to fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using .trigger(); why not call fancybox like this:

```
jQuery.fancybox();
```

Fancybox triggers depending on the selector its connected to. Not the div its going to open.

Comment: jQuery.fancybox(); is useful ONLY for click on id's.
i.e <a id="openpopup">Open</a> then I can use - jQuery("#openpopup").fancybox();

but I need the pop up onblur of text field.
Now I fixed it by commenting loading of jQuery.1.7.2.js

I am able to load the popup. but it is flickring. i.e click on the content of pop up window will load the pop up again.
Please check this demo URL - http://115.112.70.158/fancybox/popup.html 
Type something in the text field. It popup the content. Them click on the text"Content for pop up window". It flicker/reload the popup again. 
Please check it.

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery(function(){
   jQuery('#zipcode').blur(function(){
      jQuery.fancybox({
         "content":$('#formcontainer'),
         "hideOnContentClick": true,
         "hideOnOverlayClick": true
      });
   });
});
```

This should do it and get rid of the onblur attribute

Answer (score 0):

I tried another option and it is working fine now.
**Option**
1) Created a div with CSS attribute - display  as none

```
<div style="display:none"><a id="azcodelink" href="#zipcode_form">test</a></div>
```

2) In the textfield, Onblur called a JS function

```
<input type="text" name="namefld" id="namefld" value="" onblur="openpopup()" />
```

3) In the JS function, I trigered the click function of "azcodelink"

```
function openpopup() {
    $("#azcodelink").trigger('click');
}
```

4) The id - zipcode_form - has the pop up content

```
<form id="zipcode_form">
...
</form>
```

Thats all..

Thanks for all your support.

Comment: May I know the reason for minus?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery(".fancybox").fancybox({
        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        iframe : {
            preload: false
        }
    });
});     
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.smartparcelbox.com/skin/frontend/rwd/default/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script
```